# Как выбрать максимальную дату из двух полей?

Tags: mysql

Есть два поля, в которых лежат даты. Нужно определить более позднюю из них. То есть хочется написать что-то вроде

```
SELECT MAX('2018-07-21', '2018-08-15')
```

или

```
SELECT MAX(date1, date2)
```

Понятно, что так не работает. Как это сделать?

Comment: если очень хочется с max, то можно сделать так `select max(d) from (select f1 as d from x union select f2 from x) as t`. Если просто хочется решить, то вы же можете просто сравнить два этих поля в запросе с помощью `case` или `if`

Answer (score 1):

MAX() работает с наборами записей, тогда как Вам нужно работать с набором скалярных значений в рамках одной записи. Для этого существует функция [GREATEST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
SELECT GREATEST(date1, date2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, date1, date2, 
CASE 
    WHEN date1 >= date2 THEN date1 
    ELSE date2
END AS max_date
FROM table
```

вот что мне было нужно

Или с `IF`:

```
SELECT id, date1, date2, IF(date1 >= date2, date1, date2) AS max_date
FROM table
```

называется - редко используемые конструкции языка :)

Comment: да, можете еще укоротить, используя `IF` вместо `CASE`

Comment: *называется - редко используемые конструкции языка* Нет, это называется - незнание имеющихся средств языка.